# Issues were found when checking AAR metadata: androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha01 and androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0-alpha01

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, aar

I am working on a project and today the build is not working anymore.
The error is the following:

> 2 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:
>
> 1. Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha01' requires libraries and applications that
>    depend on it to compile against codename "UpsideDownCake" of the
>    Android APIs.
>
>    :app is currently compiled against android-33.
>
>    Recommended action: Use a different version of dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha01',
>    or set compileSdkPreview to "UpsideDownCake" in your build.gradle
>    file if you intend to experiment with that preview SDK.
> 2. Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0-alpha01' requires libraries and applications that
>    depend on it to compile against codename "UpsideDownCake" of the
>    Android APIs.
>
>    :app is currently compiled against android-33.
>
>    Recommended action: Use a different version of dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0-alpha01',
>    or set compileSdkPreview to "UpsideDownCake" in your build.gradle
>    file if you intend to experiment with that preview SDK.

From my research, I understand that the version from the error message were released yesterday, according to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#core_and_core-ktx_version_112_2).

Below are the build.gradle scripts that the project is using.
In my build.gradle I have `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'`. I don't understand why another version is added at the build phase and also why `androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha01` is added.

*build.gradle:*

```
buildscript {

    apply from: './dependencies.gradle'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$versions.kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$versions.hilt_android"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url = "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*dependencies.gradle:*

```
ext.versions = [
    minSdkLib        : 23,
    compileSdk       : 33,
    versionCode      : 8,
    versionName      : '1.0.8',

    kotlin_version : '1.8.0',
    hilt_android : '2.44',
    hilt_compiler : '2.44',
]
```

*build.gradle (app):*

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'

    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
    }
}

apply from: '../dependencies.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion versions.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        // For view binding:
        viewBinding true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***"
        minSdkVersion versions.minSdkLib
        targetSdkVersion versions.compileSdk
        versionCode versions.versionCode
        versionName versions.versionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true

        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'

    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1"
    /* Work */
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    // Added Dependencies
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    //
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.1'

    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:1.2.0")

    /* Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) permission */
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'

    /* This is a logger with a small, extensible API which provides
       utility on top of Android's normal Log class. */
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.10.0'

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.14.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.14.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.14.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    // Dagger Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$versions.hilt_android"
    implementation 'org.chromium.net:cronet-embedded:108.5359.79'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$versions.hilt_compiler"
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'

    // Paging
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.1.1"

    /* Kotlin coroutines */
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.4.1"
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.3.2")
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.0'


    /* ssp for text size for all multiple devices */
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    /* sdp for all multiple devices size */
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

    /* Image picker and Camera */
    implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker-support:1.7.1'

    /* Crash reporter in debug builds only */
    debugImplementation 'com.balsikandar.android:crashreporter:1.1.0'

    // Biometric
    implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0'

    // FCM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'

    // Calendar
    implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.8.0-rc01'

    // Horizontal Calendar
    implementation 'devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar:horizontalcalendar:1.3.4'

    // Stripe SDK
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.16.1'

    // Testing libraries
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3"
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:1.5.0"
    debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.5.5'

    //
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    /// Zoom image
    implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.3.1'
    /// S: Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    // Bar
    implementation 'com.github.hadiidbouk:ChartProgressBar-Android:2.0.6'

    // One Signal
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'

    // Color picker
    implementation 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.1'
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'adapter-rxjava2', version: '2.6.1'

    // Toast
    implementation 'com.github.ahmmedrejowan.CuteToast:CuteToast:1.2'
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem, but my project didn't have this *generic* dependency:

```
androidx.core:core-ktx:+
```

*But* some of my dependencies had it (you can see it with the Gradle "Dependency analyser"). So you need to tell Gradle to force a specific dependency version for your dependencies:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 45):

I had the same error today, and this is what fixed it for me: check in **all your library modules** for this import in the `build.gradle` files (you can search in Android Studio in the *Edit* → *Find* → *Find in Files...* menu option):

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
```

Replace it with the latest stable version to avoid the error:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
```

Synchronise your project and the errors should be gone!

Answer (score 21):

I have the same problem. Add this line; it's related to [Android 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_14) changes:

```
defaultConfig {
    compileSdkPreview = "UpsideDownCake"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don't want to change the compileSDK

Comment: My AGP is 4.1.3, so made changes per the [dev guide](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/setup-sdk#build-config-odl-agp)

android {
    compileSdkVersion "android-UpsideDownCake"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion "android-UpsideDownCake"
    }



Error -


`The minCompileSdk (33) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-UpsideDownCake).
Dependency: androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha04`

Comment: please add 

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force("androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha04")
    }
}

Answer (score 13):

Go through your dependencies and make sure to specify explicitly the exact version you'd be using, I had this issue and it is a multi-module project I used `1.9.0` in some modules and in some modules I used `core-ktx:+`.

just change

```
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:+")
```

to

```
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
```

or a later stable version

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

This helped:

```
defaultConfig {
    compileSdkPreview = "UpsideDownCake"
}
```

But it created a problem at the moment of creating the APK file/bundle, so the best solution for me was to downgrade Gradle.

**Android Gradle Plugin Version 7.1.1 || Gradle Version 7.3**

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me :

Project Structure > Dependencies > app > core-ktx+ > Requested Version

**Change it to "1.9.0"**

Apply.

Answer (score 2):

`androidx.core:core:` is either a dependency declared in your module's `build.gradle` or pulled in as a transitive dependency into your project. There's a good chance that it is declared as `androidx.core:core-ktx:+` which will make Gradle pull in the latest version of your dependency.

This is something Gradle will warn you against with the message:

> Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds'.

Finding the dependency and giving it a specific version instead of `+` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Like Aleksandr Zurnachyan said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684382/android-issues-were-found-when-checking-aar-metadata-androidx-corecore1-12-0/75685704#75685704).
I face the same problem.

Recommended action: Use a different version of dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha01', or set **compileSdkPreview to "UpsideDownCake" in your build.gradle** file if you intend to experiment with that preview SDK.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Frank Fortier

Comment: Thank you Hamdy Abd El Fatah

Answer (score 1):

I have found another way to fix this issue.
We can't force update all project dependencies to *androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0*, because I have used many libraries which uses older version of this library.

#### A solution that worked for me

*Downgrading* Gradle version from 7.4 to 7.3 worked for me.

My Android Studio version: [version 15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio#Version_history) (Dolphin), 2021.3.1 Patch 1

My New

**Android Gradle Plugin Version 7.1.1
|| Gradle Version 7.3**

Comment: how to downgrade  i got error

Comment: android Student -> files -> project structer -> project

Answer (score 0):

First, add these dependencies to your `build.gradle`(Module) file and sync.

```
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:$core_version")
implementation("androidx.core:core-role:1.0.0")
```

I think your problem will be solved...

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading from googlePlayServicesLocationVersion = "20.0.0" to "19.0.0" helped.