# Android studio error:Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

2 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha04' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against codename "UpsideDownCake" of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Recommended action: Use a different version of dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha04',
   or set compileSdkPreview to "UpsideDownCake" in your build.gradle
   file if you intend to experiment with that preview SDK.
2. Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0-alpha04' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against codename "UpsideDownCake" of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Recommended action: Use a different version of dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0-alpha04',
   or set compileSdkPreview to "UpsideDownCake" in your build.gradle
   file if you intend to experiment with that preview SDK.

I get this error when I want to run android project

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
    //id 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Google Services plugin // Uncomment the plugin to use firebase and obtain the google-services.json file
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.softr.tiktokdownloader"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation project(path: ':jcplayer')
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    // required to avoid crash on Android 12 API 31
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1'

    // butterknife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'

    /*admob*/
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0'
    /*admob open app ad*/
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:5.2.0'
    implementation 'com.infideap.drawerbehavior:drawer-behavior:1.0.4'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"

    implementation 'com.github.vimalcvs:Day-Night-Switch:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.polyak:icon-switch:1.0.0'
    //payment
    def billing_version = "4.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version"

    implementation 'com.github.chnouman:AwesomeDialog:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.1'
    implementation 'com.jackandphantom.android:circularimageview:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8'
    implementation 'com.github.esafirm:RxDownloader:1.0.1'
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
    implementation 'com.github.HBiSoft:PickiT:0.1.10'
    implementation 'com.github.Andy671:Dachshund-Tab-Layout:v0.3.3'

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issues were found when checking AAR metadata: androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha01 and androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0-alpha01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684382/issues-were-found-when-checking-aar-metadata-androidx-corecore1-12-0-alpha01)

Comment: I tried all the methods out there but it didn't work

Comment: You should check this url: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/setup-sdk

Comment: i did and the error is For input string: "UpsideDownCake"

Comment: i have getting the same issue  when i am using 
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1' then i fixed with      implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'